How to enable js features in substrate?
I am trying to compile my substrate node but it is giving me the issue regarding js features:
error: the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
     --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/getrandom-0.2.15/src/lib.rs:342:9
      |
  342 | /         compile_error!("the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by \
  343 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature. \
  344 | |                         For more information see: \
  345 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support");
      | |________________________________________________________________________^

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module imp
     --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/getrandom-0.2.15/src/lib.rs:398:9
      |
  398 |         imp::getrandom_inner(dest)?;
      |         ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module imp

  For more information about this error, try rustc --explain E0433.
  error: could not compile getrandom (lib) due to 2 previous errors

I am aware of this issue from here but after implementing the suggestions still I can't fix the issue.
my github repo

This is the common issue
-> Missing wasm target
Solution: rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
